# jQuery animate scrollTop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have a search form:

[image]

When I click on search btn the results get displayed which is a div:

[image]

When I click on some page in the pagination grid. The search result disappears as the results are refreshing.

Now when the search results appear again it looks like this:

[image]

The results div gets cut out and the page scrolls back up. I need to scroll down from here so as the user sees the search result and he doesn't have to scroll down from search form.

Code:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#results').height() 
+ $('#results').offset().top }, "slow");
```

Doesn't quite seem to work. 'results' is the id of the div 'search results'. I am placing the code in a knockout view model.

Trying the code:

```
$("#results").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

To see if the the jQuery is gettin applied, it gives the correct output the div results is bordered red.

What am I doing wrong here with respect to scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to do simply:

`$(window).scrollTop($('#results').offset().top);`

http://jsfiddle.net/fuggetgk/

Or if You prefer, here is plugin for this effect http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/

Comment: If I wanna integrate animate with it, should I do it this way:         `$(window).animate({ scrollTop: $('#resultTable').offset().top }, "slow");`

Comment: OK, so here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fuggetgk/1/ - of course setTimeout is there just for showing effect, You can remove it :)

Comment: It does for me, but in a flick of a second, it doesn't really animate the way down. Would it be coz, I have a small scroll area down? Also why the html,body now instead of the window?

Comment: If You have small height of site, it's possible that browser cannot scroll it to the bottom. Try to set min-height or sth like that and test.

Comment: And about $('html, body') - I've got it from jquery API docs. .scrollTop() connects with $(window) but You can't (in my opinion) do smooth animation with that. With $('html, body').animate() You can.

Comment: Thank you much, it worked! The greater the value of argument(eg.2000) for time lapse the greater the delay right?

Comment: Right, it's like speed of scrolling. If your search form has fixed height, You can adjust this parameter to get best effect.